# What characters TAR doesn't like?

Tags: tar, escape-characters, special-characters

I keep a list of photos burned to dvds for incremental backups but I got into a strange situation where a file was already burned into a dvd but tar keeps saying it's not. Here the steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir tarbug && cd tarbug
mkdir -p photos/{1,2,3}
touch "photos/1/P06-23-08_15.21[1].jpg"
touch "photos/2/P06.jpg"
touch "photos/3/P01.jpg"
```

Create a list of all files (normally I append to list once a dvd is burned):

```
find photos -type f > list
```

Now give me new files excluding files in list and don't show directories:

```
tar cf - photos -X list | tar tf - | grep -v '/$'
```

Result:

```
photos/1/P06-23-08_15.21[1].jpg
```

That shouldn't show as it's in the file list. I figured out it's brackets that need to be escaped by backslash? but how I'm supposed to know that? any list of characters tar doesn't like or uses for something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `tar`'s manpage, you'll see:

```
 -X, --exclude-from FILE
       exclude patterns listed in FILE
```

The info doc gives further details.

So `list` needs to be a list of patterns, not file names. A *pattern*, as normal, means a shell wildcard pattern. So, at minimum, `*`, `[`], and `]` are special. Possibly `{` and `}` as well.

The documentation also mentions you can change this by passing `--no-wildcards`. Then the names will be matched literally, not as patterns. `--no-wildcards` needs to go before the `-X`.

[This is GNU tar I checked. Other tar implementations probably differ.]

Comment: +1 for special characters but --no-wildcards does not work on GNU tar

Comment: nm. order of argument is important, if you put --no-wildcards before -X ... it works but if you put it after -X ... it doesn't.

Comment: @abdelsaid Ah, that's important. I'll add it to the answer to make sure anyone else stumbling across this question sees it.